# [GMSCachedTile setVersionID:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have integrated google maps SDK 2.7.0 in one of my iPhone application.

I made all configuration related to it and added all frameworks.

When I run application it gets crash with error -"**[GMSCachedTile setVersionID:]: unrecognized selector**".

I searched on internet but I didn't get any answer related to GMSCachedTile.

Comment: Post relevant code!

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue.

In the end, I found that there was two copy of GoogleMaps.bundle in my project. 
One was in project source, and the other was in pods. 
So I removed one of them. (I kept the pods one.)

And the crash never happened again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

When I upgrade my Xcode from 9.4.1 to 10.0 and my SE iOS from 11 to 12, my app encounters same question, I solve this by removing Google Maps integrated manually and keeping Google Maps imported by Pod. Then everything is OK again.

Comment: How were you doing the integration manually (looking to see where it's done so I can remove it as you suggested). Thanks

Comment: ok so in my case the duplicate was happening at the "Build Phases". It was copying Bundle Resources and Copy Pod Resources.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you have added Google Maps manually i.e added in Linked Frameworks and Libraries and also through the Pods then you should go ahead and delete the manually added one.

Since only the VersionInfo.plist was creating the problem, I deleted it from the manually added GoogleMaps.framework.

You can find the VersionInfo.plist file at this path

```
XCODEPROJECT/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd
```

It worked for me.